# How can we use a language which is not listed in react-intl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, internationalization, react-intl

I am unable to find language code "ch", or to be more **generic** can we use our own language with react-intl

As a work around, i used another language's local data for  warping

Comment: React-intl is based on underlying browser API.
Basically, all numbers, pluralization rules etc, are stored in a browser:
 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)
Theoretically,  you can implement your own Intl polyfill containing all localization rules. There is some documentation how to do so (https://formatjs.io/guides/runtime-environments/), but I don't think it is a good idea =)

Comment: so probably we need to define our own rule set for language, and all the way back, to use in our app. is it so...?

Answer (score 0):

You can, it'll fallback to your browser's language. For example, `new Intl.NumberFormat('xx')` works just fine.